# Selenium: how to get the value of hidden element which has all div tags

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to get the value of all div tags specified in attached. I have tried with all possible locators like `classname` etc, which is showing null. and tried with JavaScript also which is returning null.

Please see the screen shot and I need the selected text which is in blue color starts with "Enables enterprise IT to deploy networking services"

[image]

Comment: Show what have you tried first. Also, are there any iframe elements on the page?

Answer (score 1):

You need to research creating selectors as this isn't a difficult one.  There are numerous approaches for this element, but here's one for you: $$("#offers-popover .description").  Obviously this is a CSS selector based on the $$ and you use getText from the Selenium API in order to scrape the element text, which is what I assume you are intending to do.

```
driver.findElement(By.css("#offers-popover .description")).getText();
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the reply.. now I want to click on hidden element for the same xml structure which has div tags.. please help me am trying for 4 days..for eg: i want to click an class='popover body" element if u refer the xml screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

Since your element is not visible you can try this:

```
String divText = driver.findElement(By.className("description")).getAttribute("textContent");
```

Or, if this is not the only element on the page with the class description:

```
WebElement popElement = driver.findElement(By.id("offers-popover"));
String divText = popElement.findElement(By.className("description")).getAttribute("textContent");
```